# JQuery get child of element with class name SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to customize a calendar view in SharePoint 2013 on an Intranet masterpage. What I'm trying to do is get the text element of day of the week and strip it down to 3 characters.

I know the current structure is

```
<th class="ms-acal-month-top">
    <nobr>
        <span>
        </span>
    </nobr>
</th>
```

I've gotten a solution to work that mimics the structure on SharePoint to a degree however applying this code to the SharePoint page doesn't work.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9GG8j/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to [Msounthar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/19069/msounthar).

Using the browser developer tools I found that the JQuery was not firing because '$' was not defined. The cause of that error is that the script tag importing JQuery was in the  tags of the master page and not in the  tags.

Moving the script to the head tag loads JQuery before building elements on the page and defines the '$' operator.

Answer (score 1):

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is a function you need to invoke it

```
alert($('th.ms-acal-month-top').children().children().text());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rNA2W/)

Comment: Thanks, the problem with that script though is that if there is more than one '<th>' element then the alert just strings all the text together. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction